# Do BRIN indexes support ENUM types?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-10, enum, postgresql-11

BRIN indexes seem useful, but I'm not sure how to use one on an ENUM type. 
I thought this code would work:

```
CREATE TYPE test_enum AS ENUM ('a', 'b');
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table (
    x test_enum
);

CREATE INDEX test_index ON my_table using brin (x);
ERROR:  data type test_enum has no default operator class for access method "brin"
```

Do I have to [create a new operator class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createopclass.html) from scratch? Aren't enums already ordered?

[This commit, from 2014](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=7516f5259411c02ae89e49084452dc342aadb2ae), implies that BRIN indexes should work for ENUM types.

Comment: Version 10.6 and 11.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Aren't enums already ordered?

**No.**

> This commit, from 2014, implies that BRIN indexes should work for ENUM types.

That's actually not what that commit says. From the [commit-message on the link you provided](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=7516f5259411c02ae89e49084452dc342aadb2ae)

> This type of operator class we call "Minmax", and we
>   supply a bunch of them for most data types with B-tree opclasses.
>   Since the BRIN code is generalized, other approaches are **possible** for
>   things such as arrays, geometric types, ranges, etc; even for things
>   such as enum types we **could** do something different than minmax with
>   better results.  In this commit I only include minmax.

That doesn't mean it's there now. It is PostgreSQL for "patches accepted." In fact that commit explicitly says,

```
+/* no brin opclass for enum, tsvector, tsquery, jsonb, range */
```

Actually creating a BRIN index for an `ENUM` is, afaik, going to require some use of C and knowledge of index operator class implementation (pick/split/insert/merge).